# Pygame screen is read-only

Tags: python, pygame, blit

I'm working on a pygame program, and want to display some text on the screen.

I define my screen here:

```
screenDi = pygame.display.Info()
height = screenDi.current_h
width = screenDi.current_w
size = width, height
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
```

and define my text function here:

```
def text(text,x,y):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri',50,True,False)
    text = font.render(text,True,BLACK)
    screen.blit = (text,[x,y])`
```

However, when I include this line in the main program:

```
text('Hello',100,100)
```

python returns the following error:

`pygame.Surface object attribute 'blit' is read-only`

Any idea how i could fix this?

Answer (score 1):

blit() is a function, but you're trying to assign it:

```
screen.blit = (text,[x,y])
```

Try it without the = :

```
screen.blit(text,[x,y])
```